# use the here() function to go up a level above root directory

Tags: r

I would like to have the here function go up a level before starting to go down directory levels.

For example, my project is in the directory '/parent/project_root/', so here() sees this as the default directory. I have some data that I would like to read in that is in 'parent/other_dir/'. What argument do I need to pass to here() to have it first go up to 'parent' then down to other_dir (the equivalent of `setwd('../')`)? I'd rather not move other_dir into 'project_root' if I don't have to, but if it isn't possible then, I can do it.

Comment: I find it's safest to use file.path, so `odir = file.path("..", "other_dir")`. I'd just store it as odir and make relative references `file.path(odir, whatever)` rather than using `setwd` to navigate there. You could also check `dir.exists` before proceeding.

Comment: Package **here** is great for simplicity but **rprojroot** package may allow you more flexibility to set a different root directory based on some criterion if things are more complicated.  See parts of [the vignette](https://rprojroot.r-lib.org/articles/rprojroot.html#relative-paths-to-a-stable-root) for more info.

Comment: Consider also the following alternative approach to using ‘here’: use ‘[box](https://github.com/klmr/box)’ to manage your project as submodules. By doing so, paths are never an issue, because `box::file` will find any path relative to the *current module* from which it is called. This completely eliminates the issue of having to hard-code paths, rather than working around it (which is what ‘here’ and similar approaches do).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Do you know if there is a way to configure either `box::file()` or `here::here()` (or another function) within a project script so that the directory of the project's script is provided if the script is sourced outside of the project (eg, in the global namespace). I tried `box::file()` in this manner, but it returned the global working directory.

Comment: @kamiks What do you mean by “project’s script”? If you mean the directory in which the current script is executed: this *does* work with `box::file()` (but it doesn’t work with `here::here()`!) — but only if the code is executed via `box::use`. If you require more details, I suggest asking  a new question, the comment space is too limited.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Posted the question to the following link (though I found a temporary workaround): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70526991/call-project-scripts-from-another-project

Answer (score 8):

```
library(here)
set_here(path='..')
```

Gets you into the parent directory

Comment: This doesn't appear to be in Base R.  Is this from the "here" package?

Comment: Yes, I'll add the package call out, but I didn't initially because OPs question is specifically about the `here` package

Comment: This function seems to generate a .here file which should allow here() to see it as the root directory, but when I restarted the RStudio session (as suggested when the function ran), here() still saw 'project_root' as the default directory, apparently ignoring the higher level .here file.

Comment: @C.Denney `set_here(path=normalizePath(".."))`? (I'm not familiar with the package, just guessing.)

Comment: @Frank that seems to do the same thing. It generates the following message: "File .here already exists in ...\Parent".  The file was generated succesfully using `set_here(path = '..'), it just seems that the here package doesn't see it/look for it because the default project working file is a level lower.

Comment: Seems like `here()` is intended to always point to the top level directory of the project, so it's not really designed to work with the concept of  `..` to a higher level. If you need `here('../')` then I guess `here()` should be set to the higher level directory, and then everything is relative to that. Otherwise you need to use a different method of navigating the directory tree.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply remove the project directory string from the path:

```
gsub("project_root/", "", here(other_dir) )
```

converts "parent/project_root/other_dir/" to  "parent/other_dir/"

Or, more elegantly with `stringr`:

```
here(other_dir) %>% str_remove("project_root/")
```

It's a bit of a hack, but it works for the use case, where you want `here()` to point to the project root but occasionally want to point above with paths that are still universally valid within the project directory.

Answer (score 1):

You could save a flag file (an empty file, "flag_project_root.R" for exemple) at an alternative upper project root.

`here::i_am("flag_project_root.R")`
brings you upward to this upper project root.
`here::here('one level down', 'another level down')`
brings you anywhere down in your upper project root.

This method is interesting if you want to save your script anywhere in your project folder without adapting the script.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be to use the `dirname()` function in conjunction with `here()` to get the path to the upper level directory. For example: `here() %>% dirname()`. This should return the path to your `.../parent/` directory.

To refer to your `.../parent/other_dir/` directory, you could then use:

```
file.path(here() %>% dirname(), 'other_dir')
```