# Rproj with separate data folder

Tags: r

what would be an ideal workflow for working with an Rproj that has proprietary/huge data that should live outside the project root folder? It does have common directory root, just that it's not the project root.

The directory structure looks like the following:

```
1 . (root directory)
2  ¦--dev
3  ¦   °--me
4  ¦       °--projname (project root)
5  ¦           °--.git
6  °--data
```

`here::here` does not work well for moving up the root directory: see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51712725/use-the-here-function-to-go-up-a-level-above-root-directory).

The data files are backed up in a file hosting service common to all collaborators. It is a convoluted structure, and I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Why must it live outside of the project root folder? Can symlinks be used?

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for your suggestion---I will look into it.