# Call Project Scripts from Another Project

Tags: r, r-box

I'm building an RStudio project (Project 2) where I would like to access certain scripts that are contained within another already-built RStudio project (Project 1). Project 1 contains various scripts, some of which reference one another through `source()` calls. Is there any way to achieve this? I originally thought that by using here::here() or box::file() in Project 1 could facilitate this, however I realized that both of those functions will reference the working directory of Project 2 as opposed to that of Project 1.

For example, let's say Project 1 contains the following file structure:

```
> list.files(withr::with_dir("./Project_1", getwd()))
 [1] "assumptions.R"          "launch.R"               "output.R"              
 [4] "project_env.R"          "renv"                   "renv.lock"             
 [7] "run_scenarios.R"        "Project_1.Rproj"        "sample_script_1.R"     
[10] "sample_script_2.R"      "selected_assumptions.R"
```

And Launch.R is the script that launches code for all of the remaining scripts (code below).

**Launch.R**

```
source("assumptions.R")
source("project_env.R")
project_env$launch_mode = project_env$scenario_toggle$DEFAULT

source("assumptions.R")
source("selected_assumptions.R")
source("output.R")
source("run_scenarios.R")
```

Is there any way to execute the Launch.R script from outside of Project 1? Because of the way Project 1's scripts are tied together, if I try to execute Launch.R from anywhere outside of the project, I get errors as soon as it tries to execute the `source("assumptions.R")` command.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to source the files regardless of where they are as long as you have access to them. If you're in `dir1` and want to source `dir2/script.R`, and `dir1` and `dir2` have the same parent directory, `source("../dir2/script.R")` should do it. Unless there's more to the question?

Comment: I'm pretty sure RStudio projects aren't anything special, just a folder with some metadata in a .Rproj file

Comment: I can source the initial script by providing a relative path (eg `source("./Project_1/Launch.R")`, however, the other scripts that are sourced from within Launch.R fail to source because R doesn't continue to search within the ./Project_1 path and instead reverts to searching the current working directory. It's the nested source calls that are the issue

Comment: My exsmple uses 2 dots, not 1, to go up a directory level; you tried that too?

Comment: Yes, that resulted in the following error: `Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file '../Project_1/Launch.R': No such file or directory`

Comment: I think I may have found a way using `dirname(whereami::thisfile())` to capture path to the project's directory, and within the Launch.R file wrapping all other source calls within a `withr::with_dir` call. Though if there's another -- or better -- way, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

To make `box::file()` return the current script’s directory path rather than the current working directory, you’ll need to load the script *as a module*. At its most basic, this means replacing `source` calls with calls to `box::use`. The reason is that ‘box’ provides a *module system* rather than individual helper functions; hence, `box::file` etc. assume that they are being called in the context of a module. The [‘box’ package vignette](https://klmr.me/box/articles/box.html) gives further information.

As an example of the usage, with ‘box’ modules your `Launch.R` script would look as follows:

```
box::use(
    ./assumptions[...],
    ./project_env[...],
    ./assumptions[...],
    ./selected_assumptions[...],
    ./output[...],
    ./run_scenarios[...],
)
```

Where:

- Module names are unquoted
- `./…` signifies that this is a local, *relative* module name (rather than a package, or globally installed module which is searched differently)
- `[...]` means: attach all names defined inside the module; by default, ‘box’ attaches no exports when loading a module. Attaching isn’t done by default because it’s not generally recommended.

Please also note that each module has its own scope, just like R packages. Thus, the statement `project_env$launch_mode = project_env$scenario_toggle$DEFAULT` will have no effect in the loaded modules. To make a module see variables in the calling code, you need to pass them explicitly *into* the module.

With these changes, a `box::file()` call inside one of the modules will return the path to that module’s directory; and `box::file('some_file')` will return the absolute path of `some_file` nested inside the module (again, for more details see the vignette linked above).

Lastly, to execute `Launch.R` outside your project, with the above changes, you  can simply run e.g. `Rscript path/to/Launch.R` and this will work. Alternatively, you can also treat `Launch.R` as a module and load it via `box::use`. To do this from outside the project, you’ll need to configure [‘box’ search path](https://klmr.me/box/reference/use.html#search-path) via the `box.path` option. Afterwards, you can use the module via an *absolute* import directive (in contrast to the previous local, *relative* import directives):

```
box::use(projectname/Launch)
```

- `projectname` here would be the folder name of the folder that contains your `Launch.R` script, and the `box.path` option needs to include the path to its *parent directory*.

Comment: Thank you for providing the long response. One issue I noticed when trying to implement this on my specific code was that because each of the scripts being launched by Launch.R was dynamic (i.e., input from one script would update variables in another), by attaching these scripts, the changes weren't being passed along, which led to a host of issues. I could see the module system working well for scripts that feature static code -- such as functions scripts

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I could resolve it with

```
here::i_am("path_to_script")
source("path_to_script")
```

See `here` package website for details. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/here/vignettes/here.html